# django, multiple databases, configuration issue: "Error importing database router"

Tags: database, django, configuration, webfaction

I've followed [these instructions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) to set up Django with multiple databases. It's working as intended in my local dev environment (win7), however, when I upload the project to my live server (webfaction), I get

ImproperlyConfigured:
Error importing database router MyCustomRouter: "No module named path.to.my.router"

From the Django shell, I can import MyCustomRouter:

```
>>> from path.to.my.router import MyCustomRouter
>>>
```

I'm running django 1.2.1 and python2.6 both locally and on live server...

Any hints what could be causing this behavior or how to debug are be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had defined a router in models.py. Moving the class definition into its own file (I named mine router.py), and updating settings.py accordingly, resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

`path.to.myrouter` is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to your setting.py file

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.routers.MyApp2Router',]
```

rename your router file routers.py

Answer (score 1):

Example:

My projects consists of multiple apps like 'payroll', 'taxation', 'helpdesk' etc.  
I am using 2 db here - default and prod_db

**This is how i set router path**, 
1. In payroll app i created "dbrouter.py" file 
2. In dbrouter.py, i define DbRouter class (refer this for router code - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/)
3. In settings.py, path is set 
     DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['payroll.dbrouter.DbRouter',]